# MVC function error when button passed trying to call a function from JComponent

Tags: java, swing, model-view-controller

I am not sure if I am doing a proper MVC, but I am unable to execute `Clear()` from my view.

Main

```
public class Main{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Model model = new Model();
        final View view = new View();
        Controller controller = new Controller(view, model);

        javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                view.showView();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Model

```
public class Model {
    DrawPad drawPad = new DrawPad();
        Model() {
    }
    public void Clear() {
        drawPad.clear();
        System.out.print("HELP");
    }
}
```

View

```
public class View extends JFrame {
    JButton clearButton = new JButton("Clear");
    DrawPad drawPad = new DrawPad();
    Model model;

    public void showView() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        drawPad.DrawPad();
        frame.add(drawPad, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        frame.add(clearButton, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        frame.setSize(280, 300);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public void addButtonActionListener(ActionListener clr) {
        clearButton.addActionListener(clr);
    }
}
```

Controller

```
public class Controller implements ActionListener {
    View view;
    Model model;

    Controller(View v, Model m) {
        this.view = v;
        this.model = m;
        view.addButtonActionListener(this);
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        model.Clear();
        System.out.print("H");
    }
}
```

JComponent

```
class DrawPad extends JComponent {
    Image image;
    public Graphics2D graphics2D;
    int currentX, currentY, oldX, oldY;

    public void DrawPad() {
        setDoubleBuffered(false);
        addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
            public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
                oldX = e.getX();
                oldY = e.getY();
            }
        });

        addMouseMotionListener(new MouseMotionAdapter() {
            public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {

                currentX = e.getX();
                currentY = e.getY();
                if (graphics2D != null)
                    graphics2D.drawLine(oldX, oldY, currentX, currentY);
                repaint();
                oldX = currentX;
                oldY = currentY;
            }
        });
    }

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        if (image == null) {
            image = createImage(getSize().width, getSize().height);
            graphics2D = (Graphics2D) image.getGraphics();
            graphics2D.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
            clear();
        }
        g.drawImage(image, 0, 0, null);
    }

    public void clear() {
        System.out.println("Test");
        graphics2D.setPaint(Color.white);
        graphics2D.fillRect(0, 0, getSize().width, getSize().height);
        graphics2D.setPaint(Color.black);
        repaint();
    }
}
```

If I use an event listener from my view and I create a `drawPad` and call `clear()` directly, I am able to executed. However when I called clear form a model and controller it throws an error.

Any ideas if I am doing anything wrong? Perhaps I am missing something?

Comment: The model and the view should have no concept of each other, the controller acts as a bride between the two, this means that the model will need to trigger some event, which the controller will respond to, which causes the controller to call `clear` on the view...

Comment: Giving your Model a SwingPropertyChangeSupport object and then using it by making "bound" properties, properties that notify the support object when changed, could help solve what @MadProgrammer mentions above. You'd also have to provide a mechanism for outside classes to add PropertyChangeListeners to this support object when needed.

Comment: Also some side issues: `paintComponent` should be protected, not public, should have an `@Override` annotation on top of it, and you should call the `super.paintComponent(...)` method from within it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Stepping around the issues of trying to wrap a pure MVC paradigm ontop of a non-pure MVC paradigm and the fact that your `DrawPad` should actually have it's own MVC wrapped around it, you need to provide a [Observer Pattern](http://www.oodesign.com/observer-pattern.html) which allows the `Controller` to monitor for changes which might occur in the `Model`.

For example...

```
public interface ModelListener {
    public void modelCleared(Model model);
}

public class Model {

    private List<ModelListener> listeners;

    Model() {
        listeners = new ArrayList<>(25);
    }

    public void addModelListener(ModelListener listener) {
        listeners.add(listener);
    }

    public void Clear() {
        System.out.print("HELP");
        for (ModelListener listener : listeners) {
            listener.modelCleared(this);
        }
    }
}
```

Then, when you create your `Controller`, you would register a `ModelListener` to the model...

```
public class Controller implements ActionListener {

    View view;
    Model model;

    Controller(View v, Model m) {
        this.view = v;
        this.model = m;
        model.addModelListener(new ModelListener() {
            @Override
            public void modelCleared(Model model) {
                view.clear();
            }
        });
        view.addButtonActionListener(this);
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        model.Clear();
        System.out.print("H");
    }
}
```